# How do i get name of a location in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, core-location

Is it possible to get the names of the location using core location. What actually i need is that. when my app starts i need to display the name of the place where i am currently in. Any idea.? please Help.

Thanks in advance,
Shibin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Reverse+geocoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Geonames webservices can be found [here](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html) and are free and great for doing this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Corelocation only provides the GPS coordinates, it doesn't geocode.

You can use the MapKit framework and the [MKReverseGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/index.html) class
Be careful, according to Google's terms of service for the mapkit, this class **must** be used with a google map.

Alternatively, if you don't want to implement a Google Map, you could use another reverse geocoding service. I never tried this, so I couldn't recommend a specific one, but they are some which are free.

You could also implement a database with GPS coordinates and names (could be found for some countries i guess) and do the job on the device if you don't want to use an internet connection.

That's the only possibilities I see, i think it's all, but the CoreLocation Framework doesn't do this.

Comment: Yeah, corprew's answer is an example of what you could use for the two options without Google Map, it looks good.